# Fetch values from a JSON response in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a following JSON repsonse from a API.

"{\"status\":\"True\", \"itemID\":\"201\"}".

On client side, how do I get values from status and itemID.
I am NOT working in javascript. This is a c# class.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-dynamic-object/3806407

Comment: (Although you'll want to skip over the accepted answer which unfortunately is ridiculous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use library to work with json. For example, [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Here is example:

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000),
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)o["Name"];
// Apple

JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];

string smallest = (string)sizes[0];
// Small
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this nifty C# 4.0 implementation http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx